# Alternative to zxing QR reader library for Java/Android?

Tags: java, android, ios, zxing, qr-code

Is there any other library other than Zxing that can be used to create a QR code reader **EVEN IF IT'S NOT FREE.**

of-course a free one will be great. but I'm also willing to pay to get a library that's easy in customization and to save time.

thank you.

Comment: Out of curiosity... why not zxing?

Comment: @SeanOwen zxing is great ... but I have to get my task accomplished within 4 days, and as per your previous comments it's not accepted to use the same experience (UI and behavior). So, it means that I need a lot of customization(or that what I thought of)... I was asking for alternatives but it doesn't mean that Zxing is a closed case for me..... thank you for sharing such a great effort(Zxing) with the community.

Comment: Surely your project does not involve copying the Barcode Scanner UI -- or else, you would have to use zxing. That is indeed not cool. Reusing the scanning library inside your own app is just fine. I'm speaking out against near-total copy and paste jobs.

Comment: So reusing the library and modifying the scanner UI is acceptable?

Comment: Try Google Android vision API : https://developers.google.com/vision/

Comment: I made a barcode reader library using the Google Vision API, you can try it out here https://github.com/EdwardvanRaak/MaterialBarcodeScanner you can also use it as example code for you own implementation.

Comment: @EdwardvanRaak What's the point in using your library, and not going straight to the source.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I've found the answer for my question here http://sourceforge.net/news/?group_id=189236

it's much faster than zxing and much easier to implement.

Thank you.

**For iOS:**

for iOS (zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone) and the documentation (zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/install.html)

Comment: WAY better than zxing.

Comment: @DeshanR sir this is ZBar not, zBra

Comment: This is really what i want!! In my project, i used to use zxing to decode QR code while when my QR code is on TV and not so likely to be square(some like rect...) ZXING works really bad(Long time to scan an the wrong result!!)!! However is ALSO a very GREAT PROJECT

Comment: i want to know if there exist library in IOS like ZBar library

Comment: @MohammedSaleem for iOS (http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/) and the documentation (http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/install.html)

Comment: But guys .. ZBar is based on Zxing ...

Comment: I don't care if it is based on ZXing or not, ZBar works without questionable permissions and third party apps, that is the difference :) Thank you @afairplayer

Comment: @afairplayer What's the difference of those qr readers? Is this free? is there any tutorial to learn how to use this one? thanks

Comment: Do note that it is a GNU license, so unless you want to legally have to show your source code to the world..

Comment: Try Google Android vision API : https://developers.google.com/vision/

Answer (score 23):

there are no need to install zxing for implementing qr reader, Just create a class **IntentIntegrator.java**    and  IntentResult.java file and call from your activity.

Here is the source code for this....

[Checkout full source code here](https://code.google.com/p/dwivedi-ji-qr-code-reader/source/checkout)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;


public final class IntentIntegrator {

  public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0x0000c0de; // Only use bottom 16 bits
  private static final String TAG = IntentIntegrator.class.getSimpleName();

  public static final String DEFAULT_TITLE = "Install Barcode Scanner?";
  public static final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE =
      "This application requires Barcode Scanner. Would you like to install it?";
  public static final String DEFAULT_YES = "Yes";
  public static final String DEFAULT_NO = "No";

  private static final String BS_PACKAGE = "com.google.zxing.client.android";

  // supported barcode formats
  public static final Collection<String> PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES = list("UPC_A", "UPC_E", "EAN_8", "EAN_13", "RSS_14");
  public static final Collection<String> ONE_D_CODE_TYPES =
      list("UPC_A", "UPC_E", "EAN_8", "EAN_13", "CODE_39", "CODE_93", "CODE_128",
           "ITF", "RSS_14", "RSS_EXPANDED");
  public static final Collection<String> QR_CODE_TYPES = Collections.singleton("QR_CODE");
  public static final Collection<String> DATA_MATRIX_TYPES = Collections.singleton("DATA_MATRIX");

  public static final Collection<String> ALL_CODE_TYPES = null;

  public static final Collection<String> TARGET_BARCODE_SCANNER_ONLY = Collections.singleton(BS_PACKAGE);
  public static final Collection<String> TARGET_ALL_KNOWN = list(
          BS_PACKAGE, // Barcode Scanner
          "com.srowen.bs.android", // Barcode Scanner+
          "com.srowen.bs.android.simple" // Barcode Scanner+ Simple
          // TODO add more -- what else supports this intent?
      );

  private final Activity activity;
  private String title;
  private String message;
  private String buttonYes;
  private String buttonNo;
  private Collection<String> targetApplications;

  public IntentIntegrator(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    title = DEFAULT_TITLE;
    message = DEFAULT_MESSAGE;
    buttonYes = DEFAULT_YES;
    buttonNo = DEFAULT_NO;
    targetApplications = TARGET_ALL_KNOWN;
  }

  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
  }

  public void setTitleByID(int titleID) {
    title = activity.getString(titleID);
  }

  public String getMessage() {
    return message;
  }

  public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
  }

  public void setMessageByID(int messageID) {
    message = activity.getString(messageID);
  }

  public String getButtonYes() {
    return buttonYes;
  }

  public void setButtonYes(String buttonYes) {
    this.buttonYes = buttonYes;
  }

  public void setButtonYesByID(int buttonYesID) {
    buttonYes = activity.getString(buttonYesID);
  }

  public String getButtonNo() {
    return buttonNo;
  }

  public void setButtonNo(String buttonNo) {
    this.buttonNo = buttonNo;
  }

  public void setButtonNoByID(int buttonNoID) {
    buttonNo = activity.getString(buttonNoID);
  }

  public Collection<String> getTargetApplications() {
    return targetApplications;
  }

  public void setTargetApplications(Collection<String> targetApplications) {
    this.targetApplications = targetApplications;
  }

  public void setSingleTargetApplication(String targetApplication) {
    this.targetApplications = Collections.singleton(targetApplication);
  }

  /**
   * Initiates a scan for all known barcode types.
   */
  public AlertDialog initiateScan() {
    return initiateScan(ALL_CODE_TYPES);
  }

  /**
   * Initiates a scan only for a certain set of barcode types, given as strings corresponding
   * to their names in ZXing's {@code BarcodeFormat} class like "UPC_A". You can supply constants
   * like {@link #PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES} for example.
   */
  public AlertDialog initiateScan(Collection<String> desiredBarcodeFormats) {
    Intent intentScan = new Intent(BS_PACKAGE + ".SCAN");
    intentScan.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

    // check which types of codes to scan for
    if (desiredBarcodeFormats != null) {
      // set the desired barcode types
      StringBuilder joinedByComma = new StringBuilder();
      for (String format : desiredBarcodeFormats) {
        if (joinedByComma.length() > 0) {
          joinedByComma.append(',');
        }
        joinedByComma.append(format);
      }
      intentScan.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", joinedByComma.toString());
    }

    String targetAppPackage = findTargetAppPackage(intentScan);
    if (targetAppPackage == null) {
      return showDownloadDialog();
    }
    intentScan.setPackage(targetAppPackage);
    intentScan.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intentScan.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
    activity.startActivityForResult(intentScan, REQUEST_CODE);
    return null;
  }

  private String findTargetAppPackage(Intent intent) {
    PackageManager pm = activity.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> availableApps = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    if (availableApps != null) {
      for (ResolveInfo availableApp : availableApps) {
        String packageName = availableApp.activityInfo.packageName;
        if (targetApplications.contains(packageName)) {
          return packageName;
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  private AlertDialog showDownloadDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder downloadDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    downloadDialog.setTitle(title);
    downloadDialog.setMessage(message);
    downloadDialog.setPositiveButton(buttonYes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + BS_PACKAGE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        try {
          activity.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
          // Hmm, market is not installed
          Log.w(TAG, "Android Market is not installed; cannot install Barcode Scanner");
        }
      }
    });
    downloadDialog.setNegativeButton(buttonNo, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {}
    });
    return downloadDialog.show();
  }


  /**
   * <p>Call this from your {@link Activity}'s
   * {@link Activity#onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)} method.</p>
   *
   * @return null if the event handled here was not related to this class, or
   *  else an {@link IntentResult} containing the result of the scan. If the user cancelled scanning,
   *  the fields will be null.
   */
  public static IntentResult parseActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
        String formatName = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
        byte[] rawBytes = intent.getByteArrayExtra("SCAN_RESULT_BYTES");
        int intentOrientation = intent.getIntExtra("SCAN_RESULT_ORIENTATION", Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        Integer orientation = intentOrientation == Integer.MIN_VALUE ? null : intentOrientation;
        String errorCorrectionLevel = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_ERROR_CORRECTION_LEVEL");
        return new IntentResult(contents,
                                formatName,
                                rawBytes,
                                orientation,
                                errorCorrectionLevel);
      }
      return new IntentResult();
    }
    return null;
  }


  /**
   * Shares the given text by encoding it as a barcode, such that another user can
   * scan the text off the screen of the device.
   *
   * @param text the text string to encode as a barcode
   */
  public void shareText(CharSequence text) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intent.setAction(BS_PACKAGE + ".ENCODE");
    intent.putExtra("ENCODE_TYPE", "TEXT_TYPE");
    intent.putExtra("ENCODE_DATA", text);
    String targetAppPackage = findTargetAppPackage(intent);
    if (targetAppPackage == null) {
      showDownloadDialog();
    } else {
      intent.setPackage(targetAppPackage);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
      activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
  }

  private static Collection<String> list(String... values) {
    return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(Arrays.asList(values));
  }

}
```

And IntentResult.java for cantaining the info of the selected bar code or qr code.

/**
 * 
 */

```
public final class IntentResult {

      private final String contents;
      private final String formatName;
      private final byte[] rawBytes;
      private final Integer orientation;
      private final String errorCorrectionLevel;

      IntentResult() {
        this(null, null, null, null, null);
      }

      IntentResult(String contents,
                   String formatName,
                   byte[] rawBytes,
                   Integer orientation,
                   String errorCorrectionLevel) {
        this.contents = contents;
        this.formatName = formatName;
        this.rawBytes = rawBytes;
        this.orientation = orientation;
        this.errorCorrectionLevel = errorCorrectionLevel;
      }

      /**
       * @return raw content of barcode
       */
      public String getContents() {
        return contents;
      }

      /**
       * @return name of format, like "QR_CODE", "UPC_A". See {@code BarcodeFormat} for more format names.
       */
      public String getFormatName() {
        return formatName;
      }

      /**
       * @return raw bytes of the barcode content, if applicable, or null otherwise
       */
      public byte[] getRawBytes() {
        return rawBytes;
      }

      /**
       * @return rotation of the image, in degrees, which resulted in a successful scan. May be null.
       */
      public Integer getOrientation() {
        return orientation;
      }

      /**
       * @return name of the error correction level used in the barcode, if applicable
       */
      public String getErrorCorrectionLevel() {
        return errorCorrectionLevel;
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
        StringBuilder dialogText = new StringBuilder(100);
        dialogText.append("Format: ").append(formatName).append('\n');
        dialogText.append("Contents: ").append(contents).append('\n');
        int rawBytesLength = rawBytes == null ? 0 : rawBytes.length;
        dialogText.append("Raw bytes: (").append(rawBytesLength).append(" bytes)\n");
        dialogText.append("Orientation: ").append(orientation).append('\n');
        dialogText.append("EC level: ").append(errorCorrectionLevel).append('\n');
        return dialogText.toString();
      }

    }
```

now how to call these classes from your Activity

```
  btnScanBarCode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(BarCodeReaderActivity.this);
                integrator.initiateScan();  



                    }
                });
```

And in onActivityResult

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          if (scanResult != null) {

            // handle scan result
             contantsString =  scanResult.getContents()==null?"0":scanResult.getContents();
             if (contantsString.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                 Toast.makeText(this, "Problem to get the  contant Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             }else {
                 Toast.makeText(this, contantsString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

          }
          else{
              Toast.makeText(this, "Problem to secan the barcode.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
    }
```

Comment: While I agree this is the best way to do it... the OP was asking for something besides zxing.

Comment: This is very easy way to do this. sorry @SeanOwen I am done qr code reader by this code.

Comment: Would be simple — to bad when customer demand an integrated version.

Comment: This prompts me to install Barcode Scanner

Comment: The issue is if one wants to make any changes.. you can't.

Comment: Its asking me to install Bar Code Scanner App

Comment: Very easy. That's great. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

I have the same issue. I downloaded the ZXing library and integrated it into my project. The integration is very hard and junky and I spend a lot of time to clean the project and to used only the QRCode part. Now it works but there is a known issue with some Motorola devices Atrix and DroidX (Android 2.3)where CaptureActivity shows a white screen instead of camera. This is an issue with the library but the guys from ZXing wont fix it. It seems that this issue is also present on Htc Nexus One. This is a post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/zxing/BofniyFVZaQ.

@Sean

I know you are the founder of ZXing. The Barcode scanner app is great but using it as a library into the application is not. I suggest to decouple the app and the library and to write a good documentation to it. Also I don't understand why you dropeed the support for iOS.

Comment: "The Barcode scanner app is great but using it as a library into the application is not" ... I totally agree with you.

Comment: Barcode Scanner is not a library. It's an app. I've always asked people not to clone it. core/ has always been separate from android/. iOS support was not dropped; Steven still works on the port a bit. So, I don't understand any of these 3 points.

Comment: And it's not developped as embedded ARCode reader so it's not easily useable!