# QR Code to scan and send to a webpage

Tags: android, zxing, qr-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android, QR code library NOT ZXING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782354/android-qr-code-library-not-zxing)

I want to create an app that scans a predetermined QR Code and sends to a webpage. I don't want a whole library (so no ZXing), just a predetermined QR code that if scanned, sends to user to a predetermined webpage... So basically somewhere in the code I would supply the both the qr code link and the webpage link.

Example: If the user scans the QR Code supplied by this link http://qr.kaywa.com/img.php?s=8&d=http%3A%2F%2Fyoutube.com, they will be sent to youtube.com/watchxyz

Is there any existing framework or a guide on doing this?

Comment: Sorry, is there any existing framework or guide on how to do that?

Comment: Do you mean an app like `QR Droid`?

Comment: No no, an app that send you to a webpage based on an already decided qr code. So suppose I were to generate a QR Code on my own (like on a computer or different device), if I got the link to that QR Code and put it in my app code, I want the app, once it scans, to recognize that specific QR code (if it is another one then an error message occurs or something) and send the user to a webpage.

Comment: So you want an app that would read only one QR code? Why bother if the app only links to one website?

Comment: You want to scan a QR code, but don't want to use a library... and it will only read one type of QR code. Why? just use ZXing by Intent or something and do whatever you want with the result, I suppose.

Comment: It is for a project that I will later expand. Yes I know it seems trivial but it is not for market use or anything.

Comment: Sean Owen, is that the only way? Is there no other source code that I could use?

Comment: So far I do not see what you are trying to do that can't just be accomplished by Intent: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZXing is recommended but, here's an alternative you might try [ZBar bar code reader](http://sourceforge.net/news/?group_id=189236).
Check it out and see if it works for you.

Comment: Why would that work any differently in this regard? He needs control over the handling of the URL and you can do that with custom code no matter what. The scanning itself is a nonissue.

Comment: Thank you! ZBar is what I have been looking for! Although it is not exactly the same thing as what I asked, a few modifications and I should be as good as golden.

Comment: Yea Sean Owen, ideally that is what I wanted to do. But ZXing was what they say 'too much of a good thing.' This ZBar that slybloty showed me is simpler (and therefore easier to customize w/o dealing with too many issues). Thanks both of you for your help though.

Comment: OK. But this would have been 10 lines of code with zxing Intents. I think you did this the hard way.