# Zxing barcode library support for android?

Tags: android, zxing

I have little bit confusion about barcode type support by zxing library in android so please give me the advice here.

Here are type of barcode

Aztec 2D, QR 2D Code, 1D Code 128b,  2D Matrix (ECC 200)

which I want to give support in app so does zxing support for all these above? or any other free 3rd party library available for

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782354/android-qr-code-library-not-zxing/10783468#10783468

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ZXing (pronounced "zebra crossing") is an open-source, multi-format
>   1D/2D barcode image processing library implemented in Java, with ports
>   to other languages. Our focus is on using the built-in camera on
>   mobile phones to scan and decode barcodes on the device, without
>   communicating with a server. However the project can be used to encode
>   and decode barcodes on desktops and servers as well. We currently
>   support these formats:

```
UPC-A and UPC-E
EAN-8 and EAN-13
Code 39 

Code 93
Code 128
ITF 

Codabar
RSS-14 (all variants)
QR Code 

Data Matrix
Aztec ('beta' quality)
PDF 417 ('alpha' quality)
```

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

Answer (score 0):

Use Zxing `IntentIngegrator` to integrate Zxing in you project. This link may help - http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

You'll find the test project in the bottom of the page.

This code with `IntentIntegrator` will scan anything supported.

```
 /* Code copied from ZxingTestActivity */
 private final Button.OnClickListener scanAnything = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(ZXingTestActivity.this);
      integrator.initiateScan();
    }
  };
```