# Bar code Reader without installing Third party application

Tags: android, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I am new to Android. Can anyone give an idea to read bar code and Qr code without installing third party application ( without using Zxing Library). Just using phone camera only.? I am looking for ur answers..

Comment: without using Zxing Library? please be more specific. without any library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zxing is the best. You can use it without installing the zxing app.
You can use Zxing. 
It's a better customisable QR Scanning library. Something that can be easy to implement and have more control for the developer. 
I found some links

[Alternative to zxing QR reader library for Java/Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10782354)

Better use this :**https://github.com/LivotovLabs/zxscanlib**

https://code.google.com/p/android-quick-response-code/

You can use it without installing application.
Just extent the CaptureActivity Class after adding zxing as library project.

Comment: can you please explain how to import livotovlabs project

Answer (score 1):

Please check this library - https://github.com/embarkmobile/zxing-android-minimal. It offers a minimal ZXing setup to include directly into your app without need to download the barcode scanner app from the Google Play. It's easy to use and it's available as dependency for Gradle and Maven.

Comment: can you please explain how to import this project in eclipse